# Puntuación de una interrupción dentro de la misma replica en un dialogo

Tags: puntuación, escritura

Siguiendo las indicaciones de la RAE, si tenemos una interrupción dentro de un dialogo, se debería puntuar con puntos suspensivos. Aquí me quedan tres dudas:

1. Cuando la interrupción es por, digamos, un sonido dentro de la misma replica, ¿quedaría así?

"—Quiero el divo... —El golpe seco de su puño contra la madera de la mesa la hizo estremecerse—... ¡No te tengo miedo!"

2. Si después de la interrupción, el personaje continua la misma frase. ¿Cual de las dos maneras de puntuar es la correcta? Solo cambia la minúscula por mayúscula en la continuación de la frase.

"—Quiero... —El golpe seco de su puño contra la madera de la mesa la hizo estremecerse—... el divorcio"

"—Quiero... —El golpe seco de su puño contra la madera de la mesa la hizo estremecerse—... El divorcio"

3. En este mismo caso, pero con otro ejemplo cogido directo de mi borrador, la duda es si, después de la interrupción, por el motivo que sea, la continuación debe empezar con el signo de interrogación.

¿Habéis denunciado la desaparición de… —Se giró hacía Víctor—… tu novia?

o

¿Habéis denunciado la desaparición de… —Se giró hacía Víctor—… Tu novia?

o

¿Habéis denunciado la desaparición de… —Se giró hacía Víctor—… ¿Tu novia?

Agradecería vuestra ayuda. Se trata de una construcción que deseo emplear más a menudo, ya que ayuda a escalar la tensión.

Comment: No está directamente relacionado y no creo que exista una normativa al respecto, pero "divo" es una palabra con significado completo por si misma. En mi opinión, cuando está escrita, la interrupción queda más clara y es más llamativa si queda una palabra inexistente o si partes en medio de una sílaba: div, divor, divorc ...

Answer (score 2):

No veo ningún motivo para entender que después de un inciso entre rayas debamos empezar con mayúscula, ni volver a abrir un signo de interrogación que ya se abrió antes del inciso.

En primer lugar, vemos en el DPD que [la raya](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=kyRrDVgsOD6Xup8Dpt) se utiliza, entre otras cosas

> para introducir o enmarcar los comentarios y precisiones del narrador a las intervenciones de los personajes

En los ejemplos del DPD no se ve ninguno que abra pregunta antes del inciso y la cierre después, pero sí algunos que empiezan la oración, incluyen luego el inciso y terminan después la oración con un punto. Se ve, en general, que la existencia del inciso no afecta a la puntuación de lo que hay fuera de él.

Los [puntos suspensivos](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=c5GublcDAD6kWvCUUy) se usan para dejar un enunciado en suspenso. Parece que

> Quiero el divo... ¡No te tengo miedo!

sería correcto. Al añadir el inciso entre estas oraciones, no hay motivo para duplicar los puntos suspensivos. La posibilidad más relevante sería usarlos para

> dejar claro que la reproducción de una cita textual no se hace desde el comienzo mismo del enunciado

Pero en este caso estamos haciendo un inciso dentro de la "cita textual" (si puede reputarse "cita textual" un diálogo dentro de una obra de ficción), que se reproduce íntegramente, con lo que no hay nada que dejar claro.

Debemos notar también que

> Cuando el comentario del narrador no se introduce con un verbo de habla, [...]. Si tras el comentario del narrador continúa el parlamento del personaje, el punto que marca el fin del inciso narrativo se escribe tras la raya de cierre

Aunque el DPD no lo indica, o yo no lo he encontrado, existe al menos [la opinión](https://nestorbelda.com/las-rayas-y-la-puntuacion-de-los-dialogos/) de que

> cuando el inciso no contiene un verbo de habla, pero indica cla-ra-men-te, sin dudas ni disputas, una pausa en el parlamento, se admite que empiece con minúscula.

Contestando a la cuestión 1, entiendo por tanto que sería así:

> —Quiero el divo... —El golpe seco de su puño contra la madera de la mesa la hizo estremecerse—. ¡No te tengo miedo!

Sobre [la mayúscula](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp) tras los puntos suspensivos, queda claro que la mayúscula está exigida por la puntuación en la primera letra de la primera palabra de un escrito, o en la primera palabra tras punto u otro signo con valor de punto. Los puntos suspensivos no tienen valor de punto si no cierran el enunciado (se indica expresamente), y mucho menos lo tiene la raya. Por tanto, no se empieza con mayúscula tras un inciso entre rayas. Sin el inciso, ¿se diría "Quiero... el divorcio" o "Quiero... El divorcio"? Depende de si entendemos que los puntos suspensivos terminan la oración, y "El divorcio" es una frase nueva o no. Así:

> —Quiero... —El golpe seco de su puño contra la madera de la mesa la hizo estremecerse—. El divorcio.

O bien (al quedar claro que hay una pausa)

> —Quiero... —el golpe seco de su puño contra la madera de la mesa la hizo estremecerse— el divorcio.

En cualquier caso, [los signos de interrogación](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bH8aKhoE1D6eF5Wp4C)

> se escriben pegados a la primera y la última palabra del período que enmarcan

El ejemplo

> *¿Habéis denunciado la desaparición de… —Se giró hacía Víctor—… ¿Tu novia?

no cumple nada de esto: "tu" no comienza la pregunta. Además, en este caso aparecen dos signos de apertura y uno solo de cierre, lo que resulta desconcertante. Creo que la respuesta a la cuestión 3 ha de ser que no debe abrirse nuevamente interrogación tras el inciso entre rayas:

> ¿Habéis denunciado la desaparición —dijo mientras se giraba hacia Víctor— de tu novia?

O, si hay una pausa:

> ¿Habéis denunciado la desaparición de… —se giró hacia Víctor— tu novia?

Comment: Lo he revisado porque me chirriaba lo que había puesto. Parecía fácil al principio, pero he descubierto que no tengo nada claro cómo funciona la puntuación en los diálogos. Si alguien tiene una respuesta mejor informada, será de agradecer.

Comment: Esto es una cita del Twiter de la RAE que he encontrado en otro hilo. Es como ellos indican que se tendría que indicar la interrupción. Pero no resuelve la duda expresada más arriba porque no en el ejemplo no hay inciso.

—Me dij... 
—¡Cállate! 
—... Es que me dijo que... 
—¡He dicho que te calles!».

En este ejemplo, cuando el personaje retoma la palabra después de ser interrumpido, su replica comienza con puntos suspensivos. De ahí he deducido que habría que ponerlos después de la acotación también.